# Fatal error: Cannot access private property

Tags: php, paypal

I`m trying to finish my crowdfunding site, but when I try to make a payment through the site I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Error::$message in
>   /home/janisgoba/www/outfundit/wp-content/themes/funding_press/funding/lib/PayPal/Serializer/Unserializer.php
>   on line 826

I found in one other topic, that I should "Use **$e->getMessage()** instead of **$e->message** because message is a protected property" but there is no "message" on line 826.

Maybe you guys have some tips?

Regards,
Janis

Comment: We have to see the code

Comment: This is the code:

line 286: * @access private

Comment: Hey guys, can anyone please help with this?

Comment: The Unserializer.php code!